# odd behaviour with c++ templates specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am compiling below with g++ 11.2.0,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void fun(T) { cout << 1 << endl; }
template <>
void fun(int*) { cout << 2 << endl; }
template <typename T>
void fun(T*) { cout << 3 << endl; }
int main()
{
    int* x{};
    double* y{};
    fun(1);
    fun(x);
    fun(y);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the below output,

```
1
3
3
```

I was expecting `1, 2, 2` as output as `fun(x)` should call a specialized template function.

Can you explain this behaviour?

Comment: This is why function specializations should be avoided.

Comment: This immortal warning comes to mind https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.expl.spec#8.sentence-2

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ha, never noticed that before.